# Influence of number of steps back when using truncated backpropagation through time

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Im currently developing a model for time series prediction using LSTM cells with tensorflow. My model is similar to the [ptb_word_lm](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py). It works, but I'm not sure how to understand the number of steps back parameter when using truncated backpropagation through time (the parameter is called `num_steps` in the example).

As far as I understand, the model parameters are updated after every `num_steps` steps. But does that also mean that the model does not recognize dependencies that are farther away than `num_steps`. I think it should because the internal state should capture them. But then which effect has a large/small `num_steps` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The num_steps in the ptb_word_lm example shows the sequence length or the num of words to be processed for predicting the next word.

For example if you have a sentence.

"Widows and orphans occur when the first line of a paragraph is the last line in a column or page, or when the last line of a paragraph is the first line of a new column or page."

If u say num_steps = 5

then you mean for

input = "Widows and orphans occur when"

output = "and orphans occur when the"

i.e given the words ("Widows","and","orphans","occur","when"), you are trying to predict the occurrence of the word ("the").

so, the num_steps actually plays a important role in remembering the larger context(i.e the given words) for predicting the probability of the next word

Hope, this is helpful..

Comment: I see how this applies to text, but I work with time series in general. So there is no defined sequence length. The time series theoretically have infinite length. Therefore, I'm not sure how to set the _num_steps_.  I guess it depends on the data?

Comment: I haven't tried time-series prediction yet, this might be helpful http://robromijnders.github.io/LSTM_tsc/
or one more approach could be ..pad the data to the max_length of the input and then use lstm with the num_steps as max length

Comment: http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/
plz let me know if you figure out a way to do this